# What does this function in script do?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to this **d3.js** thing,so this might be quite a trivial question to ask.
Here is the code

```
d3.selectAll("p")
.data([4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42])
.style("font-size", function(d) { return d + "px"; });
```

What does this `function(d) { return d + "px"; }` do.

Comment: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-style):

> if value is a function, then the function is evaluated for each
>   selected element (in order), being passed the current datum d and the
>   current index i, with the this context as the current DOM element. The
>   function's return value is then used to set each element's style
>   property.

So, the function is called with each member in the array, which in turns yields a different font size for each of them: "4px", "8px", "15px" etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
what does this function(d) { return d + "px"; }  do
```

Simple, that function call stringifies d (via `toString()`), appends the string "px", returning the result.